# Could I use Pact.js with Seneca.js

Tags: node.js, microservices, pact, seneca

I just came across [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/) and [Consumer-Driven Contracts](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) pattern these last couple of days and I love it!

I'm really new to these patterns and microservices. It seems to me that Pact will be working mainly on HTTP API.

So I wonder would Pact be working with [Seneca.js](http://senecajs.org/) (I have a microservice system that was built around Seneca.js)? How to make it work? And would I benefit from Consumer-Driven Contracts using with Seneca.js?

Answer (score 0):

Pact only concerns itself with HTTP requests and is therefore framework independent. I can't see any reason why Pact wouldn't work with Seneca, though I know nothing of it beyond doing a quick scan of the homepage.

It's always good practice to separate your "framework" code from your "business logic" code - in this case, make sure that the code that executes HTTP requests to your provider is decoupled from Seneca code in a nice modular way, and you shouldn't have any problems.